# Learning to Rank with binary target variable

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

Is there a Machine Learning Ranking algorithm that can rank documents for a query using as a training dataset to the algorithm a dataset having:

- some features of the queries,
- some features of the documents,
- a boolean telling which document was selected by a user among the documents presented for a query.

The main point here is that the training data don't have a target variable that is pointing to a hierarchical relevance of the documents, instead for each query only one document out of all of them is considered to be relevant.